# Python FTP hangs in callback

Tags: python, callback, ftplib

I'm using `ftplib` to create a simple script to push out a file to multiple IP addresses, all set up as FTP servers. I wanted to display progress in the file upload process, but I'm having an issue. I use the callback argument of `FTP.storbinary()` and it works with something like this:

```
count = 0
def update(block):
   count2 = str(count + 1)
   print count2
```

However, if I try to do any arithmetic outside of a `str()` call, the program hangs. So the following doesn't work:

```
count = 0
def update(block):
   count += 1
   print count
```

Even wrapping `count` in a `str()` call doesn't work. It just hangs on the first call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just try calling `update` yourself, instead of passing it to `FTP.storbinary`, you'll see the problem immediately:

```
>>> update('')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

If you want to update a global variable, you have to mark it global explicitly:

```
def update(block):
   global count
   count += 1
   print count
```

See the FAQ entry [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) and the following question [What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python), and the docs on [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), for more details.

---

A better way to solve this would be to write a class:

```
class FtpHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    def update(self, block):
        self.count += 1
        print self.count
```

Then, to use it, you construct an instance of the class, and pass a bound method instead of a plain function to the FTP code. For example, instead of this:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(...)
# ...
ftp.storbinary(spam, eggs, callback=update)
```

… do this:

```
myhandler = FtpHandler()
ftp = ftplib.FTP(...)
# ...
ftp.storbinary(spam, eggs, callback=myhandler.update)
```

Comment: Oh yeah. I completely forgot about that. It's been awhile since I've used python. And I would agree that the class would be better, but it was just a simple little one-off utility so I didn't worry about it. I just wanted to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't just hang, it produces an Exception (specifically an `UnboundLocalError`). You're trying to modify a global variable inside of a function; to do this the variable must be declared `global`:

```
count = 0
def update(block):
   global count
   count += 1
   print count
```

This is almost always a sign of bad design, in your case it would probably be better to use a class with an attribute:

```
class MyCallbackHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, block):
        self.count += 1
        #... etc.
```